# Loading html page with data from controller with ajax asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax

I'll try to make this as short as possible.

I want to create an application that manages employee's salaries. This web app has pages for insert, update, create, etc.

My problem comes when I go to my delete employee html page. Below is the code for the HTML, Ajax call and the controller.

The page for deleting an employee contains a form with the lastname and surname of the employee that someone wants to delete.

Below, there's an section with an if statement that checks if the controller also sends a model object, if there is something, it will create a table with the requested employee ( or more employees if those names match more records).

I intended it to work by first retrieving the page only with the form, only after submitting the form the page will also load the records as well trough an controller action.

The ajax call seems fine, the app enters into the delete controller, it gets the employee, enters the if statement that checks if the call is an ajax call. At returning the partialView though, nothing happens, the page stays the same, I only get the 'success' alert from the ajax call.

I'm asking for a lot of time from you but please, if you have any ideas or suggestions please let me know, I struggled a bit with this. I kind of just get started with all the web stuff and I'm pretty bad.

Wish you have a great day!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#main-content").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'delete',
            data: $('#deleteform').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert('success')
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<section id="main-content">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("delete", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "deleteform" }))
    {
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 50px;">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    <label name="surname">Prenume</label>
                    <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introdu prenumele angajatului..." />
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>
                    <label for="lastname">Nume</label>
                    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Introdu numele angajatului..." />
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="add-btn">
                    <button type="submit">Cauta angajat</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</section>

<br />
<br />

<section id="content-to-delete">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <h3 style="margin-left: 50px">You should be able to see this message!</h3>

        <table id="content-table" style="margin-left: 50px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Prenume</th>
                    <th>Nume</th>
                    <th>Functie</th>
                    <th>Salariu de baza</th>
                    <th>Spor</th>
                    <th>Premii brute</th>
                    <th>Brut total</th>
                    <th>Brut Impozitabil</th>
                    <th>Retineri</th>
                    <th>Salariu Net</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                @foreach (var emp in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="table-row">
                        <th>@emp.Surname </th>
                        <th>@emp.Lastname</th>
                        <th>@emp.Position</th>
                        <th>@emp.Base_Salary</th>
                        <th>@emp.Increase</th>
                        <th>@emp.Gross_Prizes</th>
                        <th>@emp.Gross_Total</th>
                        <th>@emp.Taxable_Gross</th>
                        <th>@emp.Deductions</th>
                        <th>@emp.Net_Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    }
</section>
```

-- CONTROLLER CODE FOR DELETE --

```
    [HttpGet, Route("delete")]
    public IActionResult Delete()
    {
        if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I was here");
            return PartialView();
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("delete")]
    public IActionResult Delete(string lastname, string surname)
    {
        var employee = _repository.GetEmployee(lastname, surname);
        if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            return PartialView(employee);
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
```